# In a Cisco iOS container, how do I do a cronjob?

Tags: cisco

I have a Cisco LoRaWAN gateway. 
The packet forwarder runs in LXC container but is missing a couple of features I am used to from Linux.

Currently I am able to adjust some crontab features with `crontab -e`. The issue is that the packer forwarder.

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow command
0 * * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate -s /var/run/logrotate.state /etc/logrotate.conf &> /dev/null
@reboot /tmp/mdm/pktfwd/firmware/scripts/START | at now + 1 minute
```

Can anyone help out with how this works on Cisco iOS, the LoRaWAN gateway leaks some features. I did try to save the `running-config` to the `startup-config` as well. But it doesn't do anything with the Cisco iOS command `packeter-forwarder start`. But it does copy all the other `running-config`.